# Google Cloud Endpoints Parameter Limitations

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-endpoints

I am returning data from my Android Client app to my Google App Engine instance using Google Cloud Endpoints.
I seem to hitting a parameter size limit and get a 413 Full Head Returned.
The exception thrown is:
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 413 FULL head

The parameter is a String containing serialised JSON. Length wise, the string I pass to parameter is 4226 characters (Java String).
I have googled and looked at some other stackoverflow answers, but none directly deal with the length issue. 
As far as I understand, I'm nowhere near hitting POST data limitations, but I cannot find any Google documentation stating limits for parameters in the API.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: why don't you share your code?

Comment: `@ApiMethod(name = "saveCompletedForm")
     public SaveFormResponse saveCompletedForm(@Named("formid") Long formid, @Named("parentkey") String parentKey, @Named("formjson") String formJSON, @Named("username") String userName, @Named("pwd") String password) { ...`

So the formjson parameter is the one that is hitting the limitation.  However, I've read further in the @ApiMethod and see that if returning an entity, you pass it straight into the method as a Bean, not as a @Named Parameter (which is why it was hitting the limitation as it was passed as a query parameter on the URL.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I was using `@Named` parameters for passing back my `json`.  This meant the `API` used a query parameter on the `URL` which exceeded the limits for `URL` length.

Reading this article more carefully https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apimethod_method-scoped_annotations
I realised that for Entity's (and long Strings) I should simply return the entity rather than using a `@Named` parameter.

I changed my code to

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveCompletedForm", httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST)
        public SaveFormResponse saveCompletedForm(FullFormBean formBean, @Named("username") String userName, @Named("pwd") String password)
        {...
```